# Web design critique

Tags: website-design, page-layout, critique, web-fonts

I feel like this particular example has a lot of good elements. I think visually the colors work well. I like the logo design. I like the home page. But I am struggling with how to layout the rest of the site beyond that. So I am looking for a few suggestion of how I can bring this design together so I can finish the concept and complete the website.

To be specific:

- What would be a better way to layout the content for each page? I am using the same container on each page. It feels bland.
- Typography. What would really be something that flows with the design but still be readable to viewers?
- What would be a good way to layout the "events" section in particular? I always seem to struggle in these sorts of sections. So some general ideas of how people are laying out sections like this in general. Things like "My work" on a portfolio or any other types of pages like this always give me trouble.

[image: Gastro Worx concept - Home page]

[image: Gastro Worx concept - Beer & Wine list]

[image: Gastro Worx concept - Menu]

Comment: Change the font used for the food item headers - it works well for the word "Menu" itself but looks a little messy for the item headers. I'd say use the body font as the item header but in bold.

Answer (score 1):

Overall, I think you have too many misleading elements. There is a lack of similarity between them. For example, I'm not sure where the logo ends or starts, but it has all kinds of curves. Those squiggly shapes are too much in contrast with the straight lines.

The "Menu" font looks nice, but it looks more like a display font and not for a heading, maybe just one heading? For the others I would use the paragraph font, but just bigger.

I think there is no problem in keeping the same container. I would also make it taller to fit more content on other subpages and have the same look.

So, in conclusion, I would settle for one type of lines. So far you have curves, straight lines (bold and thin) + diagonal lines. The logo could use a bit more whitespace to the bottom too.

Answer (score 1):

This site looks great! I think it is presents a very classy look which is exactly the kind of market a gastropub or any kind of craft beer place is looking for. You've done an awesome job so far and I think the client will be happy.

For me, a bit is lost on the menu with the display font for the menu items. It would read a lot easier if you had one main display font as MENU (the nice cursive font you have now looks awesome) then the menu items have a different font, such as the one you used to label the navigation bar. Or if you like the body font of the menu, you could use just a larger bold version of that as a header.

My suggestion for the events page would have it run as two columns and almost like a blog if there are constantly events at the bar but if they are just using it to advertise weekly events/specials that occur (such as every wednesday being ladies night) having individual logos or designs for those events could be cool. Just an idea!